# Trying to open a new window from a WPF window, I get STAThread exception

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, sta

I have a wpf project, and I am trying to do a popup style window which is a separate wpf window I wrote. I am trying to do a simple Showdialog as I have done before on several other projects. I simply do the following from the MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    PopupWindow myPopup = new PopupWindow();
    myPopup.ShowDialog()
```

At the PopupWindow() constructor I get an

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this

Exception. I googled around, I think I understand the usual cause for the exception, I also saw the possible solutions.

1. Add the STAThread property to the Main. Well its a WPF  project, it should be generated as STAThread, and I also see in the generated Main that indeed it is.
2. Launch the new window in a separate thread. I don't want to do that, I want this window to block the current Thread, and return the choice the user made on the window for the further run.

The original project was not created by me, I had to take it over from a colleague who left since. I can imagine that he did something nasty by creating the project and there are some setting wrong and that's why the main window is not the STAThread. I have however no idea what these setting could be and where I could start to look for them.

Have any of you seen this problem? Can you help me finding why the mainwindoe is not the STAThread?

Comment: Use the debugger, set a breakpoint on this statement.  When it hits use Debug > Windows > Threads.  With the expectation that you see this code running on a worker thread.  Look at the Call Stack window to see how it got there, you need a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() somewhere in that code.

Comment: What's the contents of your MainWindow.xaml.cs?

Comment: Thank you Hans Passant! I would never have thought to check it, but it is actually another thread where all the magic happens. Why, I do not understand really, but that is what happens when you work on somebody else's code. Now I understand the problem, I can start fixing it. Thank you!